# Why doesn't the command “ ls "*" ” show anything?

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards

```
 ls "*"
```

This shows nothing in my directory. Why?

Isn't `*` a wildcard that will show everything?

Comment: Remember that it is the _shell_ which expands `*`, not `ls` itself. When you put `*` in double-quotes, you ask the shell to pass it verbatim to `ls`.

Answer (score 19):

When it's in double quotes the `*` doesn't get treated as a glob, and so doesn't get expanded.  So you're asking `ls` to list a file named `*`, which probably doesn't exist.

To see all the files, you could run `ls` without any arguments as it's default behavior is to show you all the files in the current directory.  If you wanted to pass all the files as arguments to `ls` for some reason, just remove the quotes so you run

```
ls *
```

but that's really similar to

```
ls
```

except that if you have a lot of files `*` might expand to pass too many arguments to `ls`, and also `ls *` will show the contents of directories while `ls` by itself will just show that the directories are in the current directory without descending into them.

Comment: A big difference between `ls` and `ls *` is when there are some directories along the files: The first will only print the directories' names, but the latter will also print their content. `ls -d *` is more similar to `ls` and may be more appropriate then.

Comment: @mpy indeed, perhaps waiting for the last sentence was burying that too far

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad... +1

Comment: Well, to be technically correct, neither `ls` or `ls -d *` will show all files. No dot-files or `.` and `..` will be shown. The simplest option is `ls -a`, a shell equivalent implies changing `dotglobdot` or `globignore` or some other more complex items (not possible to cover in a comment, sorry). Maybe this will be enough for simple solutions: `echo * .[!.]* ..?*` (yes, not so simple, I know, but the others are even longer to explain).

Answer (score -6):

```
ls *.* /Dir (dir is optional)
```

lists every file(regardless of file type) in either the users current working directory (found by pwd) or in /Dir and

```
ls * /Dir (dir optional)
```

lists every file and directory one below in either the user's current working directory or in /Dir. However,

```
ls "*" & ls *.*
```

will not list recursively, for that you need

```
ls -R *.* /Dir
```

or

```
ls -R "*" /Dir
```

As for why

```
ls "*"
```

is not working correctly, you are correct: * is a wildcard, and when you call ls as so:

```
ls "*"
```

you are asking bash to find a file and/or directory that has an asterisk in its name. I had installed an IDE and could not find the configuration and main files for it, so I used these commands to find the files:

(found files matching the pattern and redirected them to a specific file)

```
locate *eclipse* >locate_eclipse.txt
locate *tar* > locate_tar.txt
locate *.tar* > locate_".tar".txt
locate *compiler* > locate_compiler.txt
locate *JRE* > locate_JRE.txt
locate *jre* > locate_jre.txt
```

(Searched the whole filesystem and only prints the ones that match the pattern)

```
ls -R / | grep "eclipse"
ls -R / | grep "tar"
ls -R / | grep ".tar"
ls -R / | grep "compiler"
ls -R / | grep "JRE"
```

Sorry for the spiel, but I tried to cover most of the bases.

Comment: `ls *.*` does **not** list every file. It lists every file which has a period in its name. This pattern is not treated specially, as it is in DOS: In Bourne shells, it works the same as `*a*`. (In DOS, the `.` is sort of equivalent to an empty string.)

Comment: This answer is all sorts of wrong: `*.*` is wrong, `ls -R "*" /Dir` is wrong, "has an asterisk in its name" is wrong and parsing `ls` is wrong.

Comment: I wish I could downvote your answer multiple times, for (1) saying `*.*` in a Unix context (without explaining what it really means), (2) saying things like `ls *.* /Dir (dir is optional)`, `ls "*" & ls *.*`, and `ls -R "*" /Dir`, which are, as far as I can tell, almost totally meaningless nonsense, (3) saying “when you call `ls` as `ls "*"`, you are asking bash to find a file and/or directory that has an asterisk in its name.” (You are asking ***`ls`*** to find a file or directory that has an asterisk ***as*** its name.  To find a file that has an asterisk ***in*** its name, use **`*"*"*`**.)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) showing `locate` commands with patterns with metacharacters (i.e., wildcards/globs) without quoting them, (4b) quoting the arguments to `grep` unnecessarily, (5) saying `grep ".tar"` without escaping the **`.`**, etc….

Comment: @isanae: You ninja’d me!

Comment: @G-Man You were more thorough ;)

Comment: At least he formatted his entry well... *ducks*

Comment: [Only in DOS and Windows cmd `*.*` means all files](https://superuser.com/q/1193102/241386). Windows PowerShell and all other *nix shells treat `*.*` as files with a dot in it

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush: I wonder whether “`ls "*" & ls *.*`” was meant to be “``ls "*"`` & ``ls *.*``”

Comment: @G-Man I agree with most of your points, but downvoting for _quoting arguments unnecessarily_? That's just excessive pedantry. (Especially when later you mention escaping, which _does_ behave nicer in quoted strings.)

Comment: @grawity: OK, fair criticism but (1) I’ll plead guilty to being excessively pedantic; I got that gene from both parents.  (2) If you look closely, you’ll notice that that isn’t a fully-fledged, independent bullet point — it’s subordinate to the point about not using quotes when/where they’re needed.  It would be bad enough if they just never used quotes; the inconsistent juxtaposition of omitting them where they’re (technically) required, and then using them when they’re not, annoyed me.